# How can I append bullets and subbullets in Google Apps Script for Google docs when iterating through an array?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list of attendees. I want to list each one and follow it with two bullet points, each with a subbullet.

I tried the following code, but it lists the elements of the array, then writes all the bullets at the end.

```
  for (i = 0; i < attendees.length; i++) {
    body.insertParagraph(5 + i, attendees[i])
    body.insertListItem(6 + i, "One")
    body.insertListItem(7 + i, "").setNestingLevel(1).setIndentStart(72)
      .setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    body.insertListItem(8 + i, "Two")
    body.insertListItem(9 + i, "").setNestingLevel(1).setIndentStart(72)
      .setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    }
```

**This is what I get:**

One

Two

1. One

   *
2. Two

   *
3. One

   *
4. Two

   *

**This is what I want:**

One

1. One

   *
2. Two

   *

Two

1. One

   *
2. Two

   *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

```
var offset = 5;
for (i = 0; i < attendees.length; i++) {
  body.insertParagraph(offset + i, attendees[i]);
  body.insertListItem(offset + i + 1, "One");
  body.insertListItem(offset + i + 2, "").setNestingLevel(1).setIndentStart(72).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  body.insertListItem(offset + i + 3, "Two");
  body.insertListItem(offset + i + 4, "").setNestingLevel(1).setIndentStart(72).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  offset += 4;
}
```

- This modified script supposes that `attendees` is `["One", "Two"]`.
- In your script, `body.insertParagraph(5 + i, attendees[i])` is used. So `offset = 5` is used. If you want to put the values to the top of body, please use `offset = 0`.

#### References:

- [insertParagraph(childIndex, text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-text)
- [insertListItem(childIndex, text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertlistitemchildindex,-text)

If I misunderstood your goal and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.